# Teradata database version 15.00 does not return error message

Tags: database, odbc, teradata

I am using a Teradata database 15.00 and ODBC driver 15.10. When a query fails, it just returns an error code but not a detailed error message. Anyone have any idea about it? How can I get the error message? Is there a parameter to enable this detailed error message output?

Appreciate your help!

Stephen

Comment: How are you executing your query?

Comment: Are you using MS Access as a front-end and a pass-through query or linked table?  Or an SSIS package with the Attunity driver?

Comment: @Andrew I executed the query from SqlAssistant. Also executed from HANA studio with teradata as a remote source.

Comment: @Beth Neither of them. Use SqlAssistant and HANA studio.

Comment: SQL Assistant should give you a good error message.  Can you post your query?  Are you sure it isn't just returning no results or results in another window you're not seeing?

Comment: What happens if you hit your F11 key after you get an error?

Comment: @Beth The query is " SELECT * FROM A WHERE (1 / CAST("A"."b" AS FLOAT))  = 1 ". There will be one row of b that is zero. I am expecting an error message saying something like division by zero is not allowed. The error message from SqlAssistant only shows "SELECT Failed. 2619". There will be a further operation when the query hit the expected error.

Comment: @Andrew It shows "2619: " after I hit f11.

Comment: That's division by zero. Use nullif function to wrap your cast expression.

Comment: @access_granted I need that error message for further operation. Based on different error messages, there will be different code paths.

Comment: I think you'll need to test for your error conditions before they happen instead of continuing execution after an error happens.

Comment: @Beth The situation is that I have to deal with it after it happens. To make sure my program will return the correct error message. Not to fix the query.

Comment: Use this block in your code (with an error table to collect exceptions):       DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION INSERT INTO Errors (source,description) 
        SELECT
          'Query In Question', :SQLSTATE;